# Unity: Is Mathf.PerlinNoise consistent across all implementations / devices / platforms?

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, perlin-noise

If I create a game in Unity that is played on Windows / Mac / Android etc. is there a guarantee that,

For each pair of x and y, `Mathf.PerlinNoise(x,y)` is same for every device running the application around the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

See [`Mathf.PerlinNoise`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html)

> Any point in the plane can be sampled by passing the appropriate X and Y coordinates. **The same coordinates will always return the same sample value** [...]